# How does Automatic Reference Counting work for Value Types in Swift?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, swift5

I learnt that Swift uses Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) for Memory Management. I want to know how it works for Value Types (`struct`) in Swift.

Comment: It doesn't. ARC only apply to classes, you can read the chapter [Automatic Reference Counting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) in the Swift Programming Language book if you want to learn more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Swift Language Guide on ARC](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html):

> Reference counting applies only to instances of classes. Structures and enumerations are value types, not reference types, and aren’t stored and passed by reference.

Automatic *Reference* Counting only applies to reference types because those types are:

1. Always allocated on the heap, because
2. They must exist in a *stable* location in memory so that you can be sure that multiple **references** to the same object are really all pointing to the same exact place (this is part of the concept of *identity* for objects)

This does mean that some system must keep track of when an instance of a type like this (object) is no longer referenced so the allocation can be cleaned up.

In contrast, value types don't have the same concept of identity that objects do:

1. They don't require a stable location in memory, and every *copy* of a value is indistinguishable from another which has the same properties, so
2. Every time you refer to a value type, you get a *copy* of it *by value* (conceptually; there are optimizations to avoid needless copying all over the place)

Value types don't need to be allocated, and don't maintain state that requires cleanup via something like a deinitializer. The net result is that nothing needs to keep track of when a value is last used (since no deallocation is strictly necessary), so no reference counting for cleanup is required.

---

Advanced note: value types *may* be allocated on the heap (esp. if they are large enough), but this is an implementation detail of Swift. If a `struct` is allocated, Swift itself will maintain the allocation and deallocation on your behalf, while still passing it around transparently *by value*. It's still not possible to have multiple references to this `struct`, so reference counting is still irrelevant for it (e.g. the reference count could only ever be 0 or 1, so it doesn't make sense to track).